# Superman in Axis WWII Germany

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to think of a short story about a superhero who fought for Germany during WWII. The Nazis lose the war and he is under house arrest afterward. He is being interviewed by an American soldier who is also Jewish. The superhero is never named Superman, but it's pretty obvious who the character is supposed to be.

Anyone know which story I am trying to remember? I think I read it in one of Gardner Dozois' 'Best of' anthologies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it be Kim Newman's *Ubermensch!*?

[Here](http://bestsf.net/years-best-science-fiction-9th-annual-collection-gardner-dozois-1992/) is a Gardner Dozois anthology including the following short story with description:

> Kim Newman. Ubermensch!
> Originally in : New Worlds 1, Unwin, 1991.
>
> Alternate History – the baby Superman landing in Nazi Germany in the 1930s rather than the States.

From [here](http://blaklion.best.vwh.net/ubermensch.html):

> the Nazi hunter Avram Blumenthal visits **the superhuman Ubermensch**, held prisoner for the past forty-five years in a castle fortified with **glowing green radiation, the Ubermensch's only weakness**. The two men discuss the Ubermensch's career and his position as a **symbol of the Nazi regime**.

This Avram Blumenthal is Jewish, and also an American soldier. Quoting from [the story itself](https://catalog.pgcmls.info/Mobile/BakerAndTaylor/Excerpt?ISBN=1616961031&UPC=1616961031%20(paperback)&position=1):

> "I was born here," Avram said, German unfamiliar in his mouth. So many years of English in America, then Hebrew in Israel. In the last forty years, he'd used Portuguese more than his native tongue. He had never been a German in his heart, no more than he was now an Israeli. That was one thing Hitler, and his grandparents, had been right about.
>
> He had been — he was — a Jew.

The short story was also adapted as a [film](https://vimeo.com/13899682) ([imdb entry](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1485130/)).

Comment: Worth noting that the German "Übermensch" basically translates to English as "Superman".

Comment: @WadCheber "Basically" here meaning "exactly." :)

Comment: And I thought that Red Son was an original idea :-(